# why is shift +d selecting annotate not duplicate?

Tags: modeling

I am following along with The Bender Guru"s donut tutorial (part 3 level 1). I'm in edit mode trying to pull a duplicate from the top of the donut for the icing. when I press shift +d I get the annotate tool. It seems it should create a duplicate. I would like to know why this is happening.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not in edit mode.  You have accidentally entered grease pencil mode, probably by selecting the *Annotation* Tool (the icon looks like a pencil drawing a line) in the toolbar.  <kbd>SHIFT</kbd>–<kbd>D</kbd> is the *Duplicate Stroke* shortcut in Annotation Mode.  You can tell you are in Annotation mode because the Annotation Icon will be highlighted.  Select one of the other tools to return to edit mode.

Here is what the toolbar looks like when Annotation Mode is selected:

[image: toolbar showing annotation mode selected]

Comment: thanks so much!